# What the error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift

My application in NodeJS 0.10 is running in my Node localhost (127.0.0.1) and my link dont listen, and Discovery OpenShift ! but not running my script, error: (http://nodejs2-agenciadreamup.rhcloud.com/), my GitHub (https://github.com/AlanPS/StreamBrasil) ...help-me!!!

my code:

```
var http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  util = require('util');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/aula.mp4';
  var stat = fs.statSync(path);
  var total = stat.size;
  if (req.headers['range']) {
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

    var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
    res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    console.log('ALL: ' + total);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:8080');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is using 127.0.0.1:8080 which is not the case on openshift.  Here is the change:

```
var http = require('http'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  util = require('util');

// if on OpenShift, use OpenShift ip/port, else use your local ip/port
var ipAddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  // This part of code is unchanged, so it's removed to simplify
  // the answer

}).listen(port, ipAddress);  // <<<<< use variables set above
console.log('Server running at ' + ipAddress + ":" + port);
```

Comment: Because aula.mp4 (var path = __dirname + '/aula.mp4'; var stat = fs.statSync(path);) is not on OpenShift, so statSync() throws exception which crashes your server

Comment: but i edit the code equal yout answer, and restarter applicatiion in openshift and erro 503!

Comment: Your can reproduce the issue locally by moving aula.mp4 somewhere else.  I tried that, the server crashed and here is the error: fs.js:684
  return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/xxxxx/tmp/aula.mp4'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/tmp/x.js:11:17)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)

Comment: i edit the code question, i using your code, edit github and restart openshift application, and now ? error 503 again...

Comment: It still kills your server because the mp4 file is not readable on openshift even you put it there.  I had tried in the past, I ccouldn't read file on filesystem when I deployed it on openshift.  I think it's for security reason...  You have to store everything in the database, including contents of files.

Comment: i need exec one test in openshift (none mp4), tell me anyone script for this

Comment: what do you mean "exec one test"?  execute sytem command if that's what you meant?  You might not be able to execute system commands in your code when you deploy it to openshift, again for security reason

Comment: The `503` is coming from OpenShift's routing system (not from your app).  It's the default response when your app is crashing, can't bind, or won't start up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [include a check for a system-provided virtual IP address (`process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`) in order connect your server to OpenShift's routing system](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#env_vars).

The routing system responds with `503` if your app is failing, or if it isn't able to establish a connection.